# Is it possible in any way to generate an image from a DIV, including images that are hosted somewhere else?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, screenshot

In function of an e-mail signature tool we're developing, we're building a feature to not only export the signature, but also make a screenshot of it.

We tried working with the Javascript library HTML2Canvas: https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/ but when using this solution, all of our images inside the HTML that are hosted elsewhere, are not shown in the screenshot.

This issue exists for a longer time, hence the question if there's any other solution to render a screenshot from HTML that includes external images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use headless browser. This article provides all the necessary information for taking screenshots. https://bitsofco.de/using-a-headless-browser-to-capture-page-screenshots/